# Insert Array in existing Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("559c1d2ad8291bc9368b4568")
 tablename: "IWEO_IWBB"
 out_user: "pb"
 out_email: "email"
 out_date: "15.05.2015"
```

and want to add array like this:

```
"inventar": [
    {
        "ean": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    },
    {
        "ean": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    }
],
```

In my old PHP-Server I used the code below to insert it.
The right command is "update". In node.js it seems to be another command.

```
foreach($jArray as $value){ 
    //$uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $tablename = $value['tablename'];
    $ean = $value["ean"];
    $runtime = $value["runtime"];
    $art = $value["art"];
    $marker = $value["marker"];
    $stammkost = $value["stammkost"];
    $new_data = array(
        //array (
        'ean' => $ean,
        'runtime' => $runtime,
        'art' => $art,
        'marker' => $marker,
        'stammkost' => $stammkost,
        'accepted' => '0'
        //)
    );
    try {
        $collection->update(array("tablename"=>$tablename),array('$push' => array("inventar" => $new_data)));
        echo json_encode($collection);
    }
    catch ( MongoConnectionException $e ) {
        echo '<p>Update failed</p>';
        exit();
    }           
}
```

In my new node.js I use the code below:

```
tables.forEach(function(table) {
var tablename = table.tablename;
var name = table.name ;
var ean = table.ean;
var runtime= table.runtime;
var art = table.art;
var marker = table.marker;
var stammkost = table.stammkost;
console.log(tablename+" "+ean+" "+name+" "+runtime+" "+art+" "+marker+" "+stammkost);
    OutAccept.update(function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
    console.log(data);
    }
    });
    response.end();
    //}
    });

});
```

The output in console is:

```
IWEO_IWBB_01062015 1 name1 11337 A null null
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
IWEO_IWBB_01062015 2 name2 A null null
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

Why it isnt updated/inserted? Its the wrong command?

Comment: So are you using PHP at all on your node.js server where you are having the issue?

Comment: `'$push'`? that's a string that contains the characters `$`, `p`, `u`, etc... it is NOT a variable named push.

Comment: oh sorry, I want to migrate from php to node. In php its working, in node Not yet

Comment: @MarcB you did not read my questions. The php-part is working and is not to be discussed...

Comment: I think I should use findOneAndUpdate https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/3005513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in your code here. First and foremost to note is that you are running in an "async" environment now and you need to change the thinking on how you do some things.

Your previous PHP code is "blocking", which means that every line of code must complete before moving on to the next line of code. This includes waiting for a database server to perform an update and return the response.

You cannot use basic control loops with functions inside them that perform asynchronously. Instead you need something that can call the next iteration of the loop (or at least signal that a single iteration is complete ) once the asynchronous function "update" has actually returned a result.

The second point here is that "nothing updated" because you did not tell the function what to update or what to update the matched document with.

The following is analogous to you original PHP listing, but adjusted for "async" methods also use the [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) for the loop control from the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library:

```
async.eachSeries(
    tables,
    function(table,callback) {
        var tablename  = table.tablename;
        delete table.tablename;   // just remove the key rather than re-construct
        OutAccept.update(
            { "tablename": tablename },
            { "$push": { "inventar": table } },
            function(err,numAffected) {
                console.log( numAfftected ); // tells you how many are updated or nothing
                callback(err)
            }
        );
    },
    function(err) {
       // comes here on completion of all array items
    }
);
```

The `.findOneAndUpdate()` command instead returns the document that was modified and with the modifications only if you ask for them with `{ "new": true }`

```
async.eachSeries(
    tables,
    function(table,callback) {
        var tablename  = table.tablename;
        delete table.tablename;
        OutAccept.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "tablename": tablename },
            { "$push": { "inventar": table } },
            { "new": true },
            function(err,doc) {
                console.log( doc ); // shows the modified document
                callback(err)
            }
        );
    },
    function(err) {
       // comes here on completion of all array items
    }
);
```

If you want to add Multiple array elements at once, or if you have even a single element directly in an array then use the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
var inventor =  [
    {
        "ean": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    },
    {
        "ean": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    }
];


OutAccept.update(
    { "tablename": tablename },
    { "$push": { "inventar": { "$each": inventar } } },
    function(err,numAffected) {
       // work in here
    }
);
```

Comment: It thought about the structure and I will open a new thread about. It would be very nice if you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298624/insert-update-push-array-in-existing-document-in-mongodb

Comment: what is outaccept in your Code? In my Code its the defined Model schema, I cant still get it

Comment: @Piet Just copying your code presuming that was the correct model. The operations here all work as is.

Comment: I got understanding problem with the models in mongoose. I create the full schema and fill it up with values? `var moveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tablename: String
  , OutUser: String
  , OutEmail: String
  , OutDate: String
  , InUser: String
  , InEmail: String
  , InDate: String
  , accepted: String
  , inventar: Array
  });` or I create for every database-action a new schema? I am unable to create 2 different models/schemas for the same collection. Ill get ` Cannot overwrite `Movements` model once compiled.` (movements is my collection)

Comment: `doc.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "tablename": tblname },
            { "$push": { "inventar": table } },
            { "new": true },
            function(err,doc) {
                console.log( doc ); // shows the modified document
                callback(err)
            }
        );` produces `TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at D:\straff_alpha\routes\routes.js:177:18`

Comment: @Piet Looks like `doc` is an instance and not the model. You need to use the mode. Already said this. You use the code provided in the answer and do not make up your own things. The code provided works as designed.

Comment: Now its working, with the model. Why I use the model and not the document, which is an instance of the model? For the creation of the document I use the instance and not the model.... I am getting crazy with node.js... thank you very much

Comment: @Piet Instances created via "new" are only for use in creating a "new" object instance that you intend to `.save()`. Otherwise you use the "Model" to access all other methods. Spend some time reading the mongoose documentation and trying examples before just writing code. That is also a general principle of "test driven development".