# Insert/Update/Push Array in existing Document in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

what to do:

The user sends a string via post.
the string is parsed as JSON-string.
This questions follows the impression of the answer of [Insert Array in existing Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277435/insert-array-in-existing-document/31281382#31281382) Blake Seven to make it better to understand.

thanks in advance

The parsed data is like:

```
var inventor =  [
    {
        "tablename": "AAAA",
        "ean": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    },
    {
        "tablename": "AAAA",
        "ean": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    }
        {
        "tablename": "BBBB",
        "ean": "3",
        "name": "name3",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    }
];
```

`

The existing documents are like

```
 tablename: "AAAA"
 OutUser: "ZZZ"
 OutEmail: "test@test.test"
 OutDate: "01.01.2015"
 _id: ObjectId("559c2f04f41dde0c1b39574c")
 __v: 0
```

means:

each inventor-array shoud be added to the right tablename.

so after all is done every existing document gets added the inventor-data, depending on the tablename in it.

```
 tablename: "AAAA"
 OutUser: "ZZZ"
 OutEmail: "test@test.test"
 OutDate: "01.01.2015"
 inventar: [
    {
        "ean": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    },
    {
        "ean": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "runtime": "0",
        "art": "null",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "null",
        "accepted": "0"
    }
]
 _id: ObjectId("559c2f04f41dde0c1b39574c")
 __v: 0
```

This is my existing code and after that i got stuck....

```
app.post('/out_accepted', function(request,response){
    //request string as parameter
    var jsonString=request.body.json;
    //parse string in JSON-String
    var inventar = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Can you follow me?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as your mentioned question [Insert Array in existing Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277435/insert-array-in-existing-document)

Comment: yes it is, but wanted to make clearer the whole thing. the Inventor Post json here Different, because the tablename is inside. I dont know if it was clear in the other thread

Comment: It was clear enough, which is why you got an answer. You cannot post the same question here twice. If you think you need more information ( and this looks all the same, and actually less detail ) then you edit your original question, and possibly alert anyone who answered of the additional information. This is a ["duplicate"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) question. They get removed. And probably downvoted heavily when people see what you have done.

Comment: I marked it as solved to close it and I will later edit the other question with a few more details. thanks